# PowerShell How to Pass multiple integer parameters in a function

Tags: powershell

I am learning PowerShell and I had a question about passing parameters.  I wanted to create a function that allows you to pass in 2 integer parameters.  It takes the first parameter and 'raises' it to the magnitude of the second number.  ie get-power(3,2) would be 9.  It appears that when I run this function that it creates an array.  How do I either use the values inside the array to complete the function or am I missing a step or concept.

```
function get-power{
  Param
 (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position =0)]
    [int]$arg1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position= 1)]
    [int]$arg2
    )
      [math]::Pow([int]$arg1, [int]$arg2)
}
```

Comment: Actually, it should return a double.  You can cast it as in [int] if you want if the answer is not bigger than an int.

Comment: You call the function like so: `get-power 3 2`. Your function works as is.

Comment: Omgosh, I was trying to return it as get-power(3,2) Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Just do it:

```
function get-power([int]$arg1, [int]$arg2)
{
    [math]::Pow([int]$arg1, [int]$arg2)
}


$result=get-power 3 2
$result
```